# How to dynamically hide a div tag that was created dynamically?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

Sorry, I am still new using jquery so this might be an easy question. I am trying to setup a div tag with a table in it, with a button to hide the div tag. I figured out how to get it to work with using a id tag for each div tag, but I need something more like a class that can handle unlimited buttons (well at least 100). Here is what I tried. I put the javascript code in the dynamic returned code. Button 1 works, and button 5 6 show, but they don't work.

Please take a look if you have a minute point me in the right direction.

Thanks

code.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#remove0" ).click(function() {
            var checkattrib = $(this).attr("src");

            if ( checkattrib != "ajax-loader.gif" ) {

                $(this).attr("src", "ajax-loader.gif");
                mytimer0 = setTimeout(delayme0,1000);

            } else {

                $(this).attr("src", "req/icons/icon_checknotok.gif");
                clearTimeout(mytimer0);

            }
            return false;
        });
        function delayme0() {
            $( "#alert0" ).hide();
            $.post( "update.php", { mydata: "654321" },
                function(data) {
                    document.getElementById("dynamiccode").innerHTML=data;
                });
            return false;
        }

        $( "#remove1" ).click(function() {
        var checkattrib = $(this).attr("src");

        if ( checkattrib != "req/icons/icon_waitani.gif" ) {

            $(this).attr("src", "req/icons/icon_waitani.gif");
            mytimer1 = setTimeout(delayme1,1000);

        } else {

            $(this).attr("src", "req/icons/icon_checknotok.gif");
            clearTimeout(mytimer1);

            }
            return false;
        });
        function delayme1() {
            $( "#alert1" ).hide( "clip", 1000 );
            $.post( "update.php", { mydata: "445566" } );
            return false;
        }


    });
    //]]>
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id='alert0'>
            <table><tr><td>
                Button 1: <input type="image" title="Remove Alert" src="req/icons/icon_checknotok.gif" value=""  id="remove0" />
            </td></tr></table>
</div>
<div id='alert1'>
            <table><tr><td>
                Button 2: <input type="image" title="Remove Alert" src="req/icons/icon_checknotok.gif" value=""  id="remove1" />
            </td></tr></table>
</div>
</form>
<div id='dynamiccode'></div>
<br />
```

update.php

```
// read data from database with id tag from ajax

// return new data

print <<<END
    <script type="text/javascript">  //<![CDATA[
        $( "#removealert1 ).click(function() {
            var checkattrib = $(this).attr("src");

            if ( checkattrib != "ajax-loader.gif" ) {

                $(this).attr("src", "ajax-loader.gif");
                delaydyn1 = setTimeout(delaydyn,1000);

            } else {

                $(this).attr("src", "req/icons/icon_checknotok.gif");
                clearTimeout(delaydyn1);

            }
            return false;
        });
        function delaydyn() {
            $( "#alerttable" ).hide();
            $.post( "update.php", { mydata: "1001010" } );
            return false;
        }

        });
        //]]>
        </script>

    <div id='alerttable'>
                <table><tr><td>
                    Button 5: <input type="image" title="Remove Alert" src="req/icons/icon_checknotok.gif" value="" id="removealert1 />
                </td></tr></table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">  //<![CDATA[
    $( "#removealert2" ).click(function() {
        var checkattrib = $(this).attr("src");

        if ( checkattrib != "ajax-loader.gif" ) {

            $(this).attr("src", "ajax-loader.gif");
            delaydyn2 = setTimeout(delaydyn2,1000);

        } else {

            $(this).attr("src", "req/icons/icon_checknotok.gif");
            clearTimeout(delaydyn2);

        }
        return false;
    });
    function delaydyn2() {
        $( "#alerttable2" ).hide();
        $.post( "update.php", { mydata: "1001010" } );
        return false;
    }

    });
    //]]>
    </script>

<div id='alerttable'>
            <table><tr><td>
                Button 6: <input type="image" title="Remove Alert" src="req/icons/icon_checknotok.gif" value="" id="removealert2" />
            </td></tr></table>
</div>
END;
```

Comment: Gotta be honest...this code is pretty dense to an outsider who isn't in your thought process.  Can you pair it down to only the essential portions and better explain your intent?

Comment: I agree with clif - difficult to provide specific suggestions. However, there are plenty of tools at your disposal to select the right elements including class names, *this*, and the parent/child functions. So if you had a button in your div that should hide the div, you could say $(this).parent().hide() as an example.

Comment: hehehe... I really tried to narrow it down. I guess it is kinda complex. That's why I figured I would post it all and you could copy to a text file to test.

Comment: Post to jsFiddle.  A lot easier than pasting to a text file to test.

Comment: Would it help to post it on my site? [link](http://techscreenshots.com/test/removebuttontesting.html) Now try pushing button 1, then button 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your bigger problem is that your code loaded dynamically has some problems.

If you copy-paste that code into a html file and test it in your browser you'll see some errors.

Like for instance:

- `$( "#removealert1 )` should be `$( "#removealert1" )`
- `id="removealert1 />` should be `id="removealert1" />`
- Just before your CDATA closures (`//]]>`) you have a couple loose `});` that should be deleted

I think that should make your dynamic code work.

Last but not least... back to your main page, using `document.getElementById("dynamiccode").innerHTML=data;` seems to strip out your `<script>`s, I tested using `$("#dynamiccode").html(data)` instead and it worked, at least on Firefox... don't know about the other browsers though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry don't mind the javascript errors. It was just user error posting to this site. But, you are right using $("#dynamiccode").html(data) works. Hmm... well do I go with manually setting up each table or try to figure it out on cybernate's idea. Oh well... thanks guys.

Comment: Ok not perfect but it's working 100% all buttons on firefox and IE. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know JQuery, and I confess I didn't really understand the whole question,  but will try say something that might help...

If you don't want to use a special ID for each of your divs you can try to use some kind of closure to pass this info:

```
function make_hider(dom_node){
    function hider(){
        dom_node.hide() //Do anything you want with `dom_node`
    }
    return hider;
}
```

So you can do something like

```
for each button:
    this_buttons_div = button.parentNode;
    button.onclick = make_hider(this_buttons_div);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use live function of jquery to wireup click handlers for dynamically added elements.
Try changing the click handler used in the code for "#remove1"to as below:

```
$("input[id^=remove]")live("click", function () {
    var checkattrib = $(this).attr("src");
    if (checkattrib != "req/icons/icon_waitani.gif") {
        $(this).attr("src", "req/icons/icon_waitani.gif");
        mytimer1 = setTimeout(delayme1, 1000);
    } else {
        $(this).attr("src", "req/icons/icon_checknotok.gif");
        clearTimeout(mytimer1);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: ok I think this is where I need to go... thanks a ton for the response... I've been hitting my head for a while on this.